# How do I properly render Angular routes using the Express framework?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, url-routing, express-generator

I have installed the `express-generator` package with npm and used the `express myApp` command to generate my app. I am having trouble working with the routes. I understand that there are Express routes, which are used for the backend stuff, and Angular routes, which are for the frontend. **The problem**: none of my routes besides the index are rendering. So my file structure is:

```
/myApp
  /bin
  /node_modules
  /public
    /images
    /js
      /controllers
      app.js
    /stylesheets
  /routes
    index.js
  /views
    error.jade
    index.jade
    layout.jade
    about.jade
  app.js
  package.json
```

My `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

My `routes/index.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'myApp' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

From what I understand, the above serves up the index and then from there the Angular routes take over and load partial templates. My Angular routes are in `public/js/app.js`:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/views/index.jade',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: '/views/about.jade',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index' });
    }]);
```

So when I have an anchor tag link to my about page in the `layout.jade` template:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en', ng-app='myApp')
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    base(href='/')
  body
      header.header
      h1.title MY TITLE
      ul.navbar
        li
          a.about(href='/about') About

  block content
```

And I load up my server and click the "about" link, I get a 404 error. In my console I see a 404 for `index.jade` AND for `about.jade`, but my home page loads the content of `index.jade` anyway.

I have tried changing the `href` in my anchor tag from `/about` to `#/about`, and then instead of giving me a 404 when I click the link, the url changes to `localhost:3000/#/about` but the content of the page doesn't change at all. It still shows the content of `index.jade`.

Also not sure if relevant, when I hit localhost:3000 in the browser it automatically adds /#/, so the full url shows `http://localhost:3000/#/`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Also please let me know if I should provide any more information/code. Thank you!

Comment: Where are you loading `public/js/app.js` in `layout.jade`? Looks like a missing script tag for `ui-router` and your app. Assuming those are both loaded, it looks like you're missing the [`ui-view`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view) directive

Comment: @Sean3z Is `ui-router` another piece of angular? In my `index.jade` file I have script tags for `angular`, `angular-route`, my `public/js/app.js` (which contains my angular routes), and my controller. I'm not familiar with the `ui-view` directive, and I'm not sure if I should ditch Jade's "block content" and use a `div(ng-view)` instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jade's `block content` but, the ui-router does require that `ui-view` directive. Otherwise, I don't believe angular will intercept route changes. PS: You also have `.otherwise({redirectTo: '/index'});` but there is no `/index` route defined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the routes for the views (error.jade, and about.jade) are not setup in your routes.js file.  If you go to the link http://localhost:3000/views/about.jade do you see anything?

Comment: Do you mean in my routes/index.js file? Sorry I am new to angular/express. No I get a 404 error if I try to view that link. But like I said layout.jade renders, and underneath it displays a 404 error. I'm not sure how I should be including my views.. with the `block content` or with a `div(ng-view)`, and I can't seem to figure out how to route either one correctly.

Comment: 404 means your routes aren't setup to deliver tempaltes in views - this file needs setting up correctly - outes/index.js